# Laravel add API Resources add attribut only when use collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to **add attribut** to resource when we **use** collection !

PostResource :

```
 public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'content' => $this->content,
            'user' => new UserResource($this->whenLoaded('user')),
        ];
    }
```

PostCollection :

```
 public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection
        ];
    }
```

in controller :

```
     $posts =  Post::with('user')->get();
     return  PostResource::collection($posts);
```

return

```
["data": { ["id":1 , "content" : "some test" , "users": [....] }]
```

we want to add another attribut (short_text)

```
["data": { ["id":1 , "content" : "some test" , "users": [....] , "short_text" : substr($this->content",0,255) }]
```

how to do it ?

we don't want to edit the PostResource  because the short_text will be included on every request.

we wan't to include it when we use collection only !

so:

localhost/api/posts

return

```
["data": { ["id":1 , "content" : "some test" , "users": [....] , "short_text" : substr($this->content",0,255) }]
```

and

localhost/api/post/1

return :

```
["id":1 , "content" : "some test" , "users": [....] ]
```

without the short_text attribut

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections), you could do this:

```
class PostCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection,
            'short_text' => 'my-short-text',
        ];
    }
}
```

Of course, you can shape it as you like to have the desired structure.

Comment: this is not what we what , it will  retrun `{
"data": [],
short_text: "my-short-text"
} ` , we want to add the short_text in each resource

`{"data": [ {"id":1 , "short_text": "my-short-text" }, {"id":2 , "short_text": "my-short-text"} ]}`